# При заполнении двумерного массива элемент с индексом [0][0] = null. Заполнение начинается с [1][1], как исправить?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter size array matrix: ");
    int y = in.nextInt ();
    String[][]arrayMarix = new String[y][y];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayMarix.length;i++)
      {         
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayMarix[i].length; j++)
            {
               System.out.print ("Enter elements matrix: ");
               String elementsMatrix = in.nextLine ();
               arrayMarix[i][j] = elementsMatrix;
            }

      }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayMarix.length; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayMarix[i].length; j++)
        {
        System.out.print (arrayMarix[i][j]+" \n");

        }
      }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.print ("Enter size array matrix: ");
int y = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine(); // !!!
String[][]arrayMarix = new String[y][y];
```

Comment: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: @MRX Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Да, вы правы. А зачем нужно дополнительно писать эту строчку?

Comment: @MRX Потому что `nextInt` не считывает конец строки.